# NSString substring processing

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

I have a string with the following value:

> [{ProjLead=irshad, ProjName=irshad proj, ProjectId=365}]

I would like to get the value for ProjLead, ProjName and ProjectId separately. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not use a more standardized format such as JSON?

Comment: Thanks for the responce guys.... i got the answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine some methods from [NSString class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"[{ProjLead=irshad, ProjName=irshad proj, ProjectId=365}]";
NSString *parametersString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, string.length - 4)];
NSArray *parameters = [parametersString componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *parameter in parameters) {
    [values addObject:[[parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

`values` array is what you want.